# Sort dropdown box in alphabetical order

Tags: php

I have this code that I need to order alphabetically. Any help?

```
$first = JHTML::_('select.option', 0, _JSHOP_SEARCH_ALL_MANUFACTURERS, 'manufacturer_id', 'name');

    $_manufacturers = JTable::getInstance('manufacturer', 'jshop');

    $manufacturers = $_manufacturers->getList();

    array_unshift($manufacturers, $first);

    $list_manufacturers = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $manufacturers, 'manufacturer_id', 'class = "inputbox" size = "1"','manufacturer_id','name' );
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array using **sort**

```
sort($manufacturers);
```

Comment: sort() does an in-place sort and returns a boolean. you've just destroyed OP's array by overwriting it with that boolean.

Comment: It's been a long day! Fixed.

Comment: It sorts by id, and I need it to sort by name.